# .htaccess rewrite w/ regular expression and ?lang=en parameter

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need a hand with creating a regex rewrite rule for my .htaccess.

Here's the problem. My previous URLs structure was:

```
http://example.com/whatever-the-url-is/?lang=en
```

now I turned it into

```
http://example.com/en/whatever-the-url-is/
```

I'd like to create an .htaccess URL that 301 redirects all the URLs from the previous structure to the new one.

Also the .htaccess is shared between different domains, and so there should be
`RewriteCond %{http_host} !^example.com$ [NC]` condition at the beginning...

Is it possible? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You'll have to show what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)lang=(.+?)(?:&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1? [R=301,L]
```

You can add the `RewriteRule` after `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:en|fr|sp)/ [NC]
```

Where you test if `lang`code is already in the url.

Comment: Hi Croises, thank you very much
The first three lines are 100% working! What's changing if I add


`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(?:en|fr|sp)/ [NC]`


after the first condtion?

Comment: With this test you avoid problem with :`http://example.com/en/whatever-the-url-is/?lang=en`